# Can I get my custom validator to use data from the form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to use a custom validator to verify that the user signs up with a bitcoin address they own. I will require the user to sign a random base64 string with the bitcoin address they submit through the signup form and paste the signature to the same form.

I use the gem [bitcoin-cigs](https://github.com/michaelgpearce/bitcoin-cigs) to verify the signature but it only works if all the arguments (except the `record, attribute, value` required by `validate_each`) are literal strings, like this:

```
def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
  unless true == BitcoinCigs.verify_message("12vvMNrVrUJjg8xqibmidg6yLxwd3m2pYL", "G0kYthikuHCeLMi4PPrp1EhE23+JaIJJgi9vZ71xVMG0pHi0DzpQ3YzxF6R3oFcNC+vSW8Z1xTcWkg3Qg0tFx0s=", "HxmIaOCscmXVZueZ/AgOxA==")
    record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "is invalid")
  end
end
```

I want to be able to pass whatever the user enters into the bitcoin address field as the first argument, what they enter into the signature field as the second and the base64 string generated by a helper method and shown to the user as the last, like this:

```
def validate_each(record, attribute, value, address = [CONTENT OF ADDRESS FIELD], signature = [CONTENT OF SIGNATURE FIELD], message = [GENERATED STRING])
  unless true == BitcoinCigs.verify_message(address, signature, message)
    record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "is invalid")
  end
end
```

Is that possible or is there a better way?

I have tried everything I can think of and googled but I can't figure it out.
I'm a complete beginner and this is the first thing I have ever made that is intended to be used for anything so I am sorry if this is a stupid question.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've got the `record` in the `validate_each` method, I'd imagine you can just call `record.address` (or `record.<any attribute or method you want>` at anytime inside of your `validate_each` method. Since the record should have its attributes set before any validations fire the contents of that field will be set from the form already.